# Is there a way to show emoji's button in soft-keyboard in a webview app?

Tags: android, android-webview, android-softkeyboard, emoji

Is no way to define something like an edittext with `"textShortMessage"` because is a web input.

Overriding `onCreateInputConnection` of WebView and setting `outAttrs.inputType = InputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_SHORT_MESSAGE;` doesn't work.

Or  with imeOptions like `outAttrs.imeOptions = EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_NONE;` only switches the "go key" to "next key".

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to force this.  The keyboard is a separate app, and may choose what keys to show.  There is no way to force it to.  For context changing keys, most keyboards look at a few clues like input type and whether its multi-line.  However anything that works for one keyboard may break it on another.